# livewire 3 how to store foreach value using form

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, livewire-3

hello I'm new for livewire 3 I have table inside form, data table having  radio button for yes or no
after selecting yes or no I'm going to submit that form that time I want to store fetch detail like id and name along this. now I'm any getting radio button value, me to solve

form page
[image]
my code form

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="Save" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="card card-bordered card-preview table-responsive ">
        <div class="card-inner "> 
          <table class="datatable  table   ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">SL</th>
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">ID No</th> 
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">NAME</th>
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">YES</th>
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">NO</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
 @foreach ($UserDetail as $key=>$UserDetails) 
 @php $ID = 0+$key @endphp
<td style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
                {{ $key + 1  }}
              </td> 
              <td style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
                {{ $UserDetails->id }}
              </td>
              <td style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
                {{ $UserDetails->name }}
              </td>
              <td style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-control-md custom-radio ">
                  <input type="radio" wire:model="TableInput.{{$ID}}.data" class="custom-control-input" name="TableInputs[{{$ID}}]" id="sv2-preference-fedev{{$ID}}" value="YES" required>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="sv2-preference-fedev{{$ID}}"></label>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
                <div style="text-align: center;" class="custom-control custom-control-md custom radio"><input type="radio" wire:model="TableInput.{{$ID}}.data" class="custom-control-input" name="TableInputs[{{$ID}}]" id="sv2-preference-uxdis{{$ID}}" value="NO" required>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="sv2-preference-uxdis{{$ID}}"></label>
                </div>
              </td> 
              </tr> 
      @endforeach 
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div  >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">SAVE  </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**Controller**
class StudentAttendance extends Component
{

```
public $name; 
public $id;  
public $TableInput = [];


public function mount()
{
  $this->User       = User::all();   
}

public function Save() 
{   
    $bel = Data::create([ 
         
        'Id'                     => $value['Id'],
        'name'                   => $value['name'],
        'data'                   => $value['data'],
    ]);
} 
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save the form on the click of **save** button, you may
create the table in the form with the help of an array. You can convert your collection to array like this:

```
$this->user = User::get()->toArray();
```

then in your blade file you can be bind the model with input fields as:

```
@foreach ($user as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td style=" border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
            <input type="text" wire:model="user.{{ $key }}.first_name">
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

In this manner, you can iterate through the user array within the **save()** method to save the data:

```
public function save()
{
    ...
    ...
    foreach ($this->user  as $key => $value) {
        $bel = Data::create($value);
    }
    ...

}
```

You can also use batch **insert/update** as per your usecase.

Comment: thank u for your answer now i can pass first_name by wire:model="user.{{ $key }}.first_name" now how to store data of YES OR NO redio button value help me

Comment: you may bind the model from user collection to the radio button .i.e. **Yes** or **No** to store their values.
e.g. if you would like to store the yes/no value in **status** column of the user collection, you may bind the model as:

`wire:model="user.{{ $key }}.status` to both the radio inputs